# Is it possible to directly execute a python package like a script (without "python -m ...")?

Tags: python

For single-file scripts, I can always execute them directly, at least on linux, by setting executable permissions on the script and adding a shebang (`#! /bin/python`) at the top of the file.

Is an equivalent possible for packages, so that I don't need to prefix the package name with `python -m some_package` on the command line?

Update: I'm aware there are workarounds, such as wrapping it in a script. Not only is this not always practical, but also my question isn't about finding any way to do it, rather to understand what the "official" analog to running "some_script.py" directly, but for packages, assuming that such an analog even exists at all or is simply not intended or not defined anywhere.

Comment: Typo: The 1st line should be "`#!/bin/python`" (no space). Read `man python` and try `#!/bin/python -m some_package`.

Comment: shebang is correct and more legible and always works. if not, please provide references, since "man python" doesn't seem to mention it. Moreover, your second form is a more complicated form of what I'm already doing. I don't think you even read the question, let alone "man python".

Comment: I do not have python anymore, but only have python3. So all my shebangs are `#!/usr/bin/python3` Or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` Seen discussions on which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap it in a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m some_package your_script
```

Store the above on your `$PATH` (`~/bin`), call it `foo`, make it executable (`chmod u+x ~/bin/foo`), then call it as `foo`.